# How can I get indentation to be included in a multiline value when read from configparser in python?

Tags: python, ini, configparser

I have some config file like this:

```
[main]
key_one   =
  hello
    this
      is
        indented
```

But when I read it using the configparser library in python like so:

```py
import configparser
cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read("path/to/file.ini")
print(cfg["main"]["key_one"])
```

Prints out:

```
hello
this
is
indented
```

I've tried using tabs, more than two spaces per indent, nothing seems to work. How can I get configparser to recognize indents?

Comment: Try putting quotes around it

Comment: Quotes are included the value, with leading and trailing whitespace continuing to be removed. I don't think the file format supports formatted text.

Comment: @pitto How do I try with string literal?

Comment: @Pitto That's Python source code syntax, not config file syntax.

Comment: If you read the documentation of the file format, it says that indentation is used to recognize multi-line values. The amount of indentation is ignored, except that it has to be indented more than the initial line of the key.

Comment: Note, too, that the newline following the `=` is considered part of the value.

Comment: Whitespaces are stripped in the configparser source. [Link here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/08faf0016e1ee590c78f64ddb244767c7801866a/Lib/configparser.py#L1038) you would need to overwrite the _read() method and remove stripping.

Comment: I would hesitate to duplicate a 100+-line private method just to remove one line, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parser itself will always strip leading whitespace; as far as I can tell, there is no (recommended) way to change that.

A workaround is to use a non-whitespace character to indicate the beginning of your formatted text, then strip that after reading the file. For example,

```
[main]
key_one   =| hello
           |   this
           |     is
           |       indented
```

Then in your script

```
import configparser
import re

cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read("tmp.ini")
t = cfg["main"]["key_one"]
t = re.sub("^\|", "", t, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(t)
```

which produces

```
$ python3 tmp.py
 hello
   this
     is
       indented
```

The value starts immediately after the `=` (I moved your first line up, assuming you didn't really want the value to start with a newline character). The parser preserves any non-trailing whitespace *after* `|`, as the first non-whitespace character on each line. `re.sub` will remove the initial `|` from each line, leaving the desired indented multi-line string as the result.